# AWS cognito getting weird message although user still exist

Tags: amazon-cognito

What does this message mean? User still exist in aws cognito.

```
NotAuthorizedException: The user has been deleted for the associated refresh token
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Cognito's Api (here Java), we can see that:

```
/**
 * Constructs a new NotAuthorizedException with the specified error message.
 *
 * @param message
 *        Describes the error encountered.
 */
public NotAuthorizedException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

Now the message says the user is deleted for token refresh, so I'm assuming somebody disabled the user. Could you verify that there is no diffrerence between the targeted user; and the rest of users? What is the *status* of the user?

Comment: User status is CONFIRMED and Enabled:true. And no one disabled this user. This user looks same to me.

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi What about if you force the user to change his/her password? Is it feasible? Do you have any logs from your app that authenticates this user through Cognito?